# Creators Update and bcdedit change?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, bcdedit

Does anyone know if creators update introduced changes to bcdedit? My searching hasn't turned up much yet.

However, a standard script that I used to get machines setup for a safe mode reboot no longer works on my creators mode rigs. However, it does work on some non-creators Win 10 machines nearby.

```
bcdedit /set {current} safeboot network
```

Error: "The set command specified is not valid."

Is there an option that might work for *all* Win 10 versions?

Comment: *Does anyone know if creators update introduced changes to bcdedit?* - It did not.  What you are using should work.

Comment: And if it has failed on 3 creators update rigs so far?

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't I feel silly...

Turns out this only works from an elevated command prompt. It does NOT work from an elevated PowerShell.